# Mercurial Over SSH Bitbucket: no suitable response from remote hg

Tags: windows, ssh, mercurial, tortoisehg, pageant

I have a weird problem with my mercurial environment on windows 10.
i usually work with ssh to connect to my Bitbucket repositories and it works fine but suddenly it stopped.

When i try to Pull, Push, Clone or any other command i started to get this error:
[pagent error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5nKf.png)

and the log says:

```
pulling from ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/<my repository>
no suitable response from remote hg
[command returned code 255 Thu Apr 20 11:38:49 2017]
```

this is the same output even when '--verbose' used and no other error messages happens.

Usually i use mercurial tortoiseplink to load my ssh keys but i also tried to use pagent and the same error occures.

just to be clear, the problem is not with my ssh key or bitbucket:

1. i also use git-scm and there everything works fine, it connects to bitbucket over ssh with pagent and i have no problems.
2. i tried to clone the repository on my ubuntu with the same ssh key and i have no problems there.
3. other co workers have no problem in there windows environment

things i tied to do:

1. Reinstall Mercurial
2. Remove SVN in order to avoid any tortoiseplink conflicts
3. Load another ssh key to bitbucket
4. use tortoiseplink from SVN installation
5. i tried to use other internet connection
6. i tried to disable the windows firewall
7. close any VPN connections i have

and nothing seems to help.... :/

does somebody have any idea how to solve this issue?

sharon

Comment: For now i switch to using OpenSSH instead of TortoisePlink or Pageant and it seems to work fine with the same ssh key. it seems that there is some problem with the integration between mercurial and TortoisePlink. if someone still have any idea why this happens i'll be happy to hear!

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [the Bitbucket documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-ssh-issues-271943403.html#TroubleshootSSHIssues-Permissiondenied(publickey)orNosuitableresponsefromremote) this error means that your SSH public key is not being accepted by bitbucket's servers. Please see the page I linked for further steps to debug your SSH connection.

Comment: This is not the the issue in my case. i don't get the "Permission denied (publickey)" error only the error i noted (no suitable response from remote hg). The public key i use is good cause git-scm uses the same running 'Pageant' (as mercurial does) and it works fine with Bitbucket and mercurial used the same key as well and just stopped working.

Comment: Right, see the page I linked to. "no suitable response from remote hg" can also mean that your public key isn't working. If you do `ssh -Tv hg@bitbucket.org` do you get a message saying you logged in properly?

Comment: You mean doing so with Putty? Plink?, this is windows.. right now the only ssh link i have is to OpenSSH that i set yesterday and with this its works

Answer (score 0):

OS: Windows 10

Sourcetree: 3.1.2

SSH Client: Putty / Pageant

In my case the ssh key setting seems to have been deleted by the latest update to 3.1.2, i had to go to the config setting and deselect / reselect Putty as SSH Client under

```
Tools > Options > SSH Client Configuration.
```

After that it worked.